# CSV to Gridview in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, gridview

Please advice me how to upload a csv file to display on grid view ?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }    

  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

UPDATE :

please advice me where i was wrong

i want to add rows when submiting data in my form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" )
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;

        }
    }
```

Comment: "upload" means ASP.NET?  Use the tags to tell us what GUI framework you're on.

Comment: your question as it stands (two empty methods) does not let us know what you have tried so far. step 1: upload a file, step 2: read the file - once you have cracked that you will probably find you can solve the rest easily (bind the read contents of the file to the grid).

Comment: @HenkHolterman : no using c#

Comment: Read from the file, split the strings as required, add to a `DataTable` and use that `DataTable` as the data source of your `DataGridView`. Did you try doing this?

Comment: @NeilThompson : first i tried to add a data uisng a from to gridview, if i put my code can u advice me where i was wrong

Comment: @shree.pat18 : can you check my question update section , and help me to fix why new rows are not adding when entering data..

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)` iterates over the existing rows. Your code makes no attempt to Add a row.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx is the best place to start.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : i tried again , kindly refer the updated section . now its adding empty rows . please advice

Comment: `Rows[0]` should be `Rows[newCount-1]` os something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Set `datagridview` property `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false`.

This should allow adding new row at `Rows[0]`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" )
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: On repeatedly clicking on `button1` you will be adding blank rows in your grid.

**Solution to Load a CSV file directly in DataGridView**:

```
string[] allRows = File.ReadAllLines(@"yourcsvfilepath.csv");

foreach (string sRow in allRows)
{
     string[] arrRow = sRow.Split(new char[] { ',' });
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrRow);
}
```

Assumption: Number of columns added in Design Time.

Comment: You want to group data in datagridview? if yes then `I think` no support in datagridview.

Comment: Use `ListView` control for grouping of data.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;
```

Try

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
```

Comment: hmm, not quite sure what you want to do. Do you want an extra column with more information? Maybe you can describe me an example case?

Comment: Then I suggest a dropdownlist after the three textboxes with a list of the groups. Then add an extra column whit to gridview with groupinfo.